# How to parse a third table in a webpage using simple html dom parser in php

Tags: php, html, parsing

My webpage Contains 8 Tables. I Want Parse the 3rd Table

Page Source for my 1st, 3rd, 5th & 7th Table: (All Contains 80 Elements)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="cricket-performanceTable">
```

Page Source for my 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th Table: (Elements vary according to the match)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="cricket-performanceTable noBorderTop">
```

So I Parsed like this:

```
 $name = $html->find('div[class=cricket-accorContent] table[class=cricket-performanceTable] td');
```

It working upto first table ($name[80]).

If I Print ($name[81]) It Displaying 2nd Table's first Element. But I want to Print 3rd Table's 1st Element

Eventhough `table[class= ]` is different. 1st Table `table[class=cricket-performanceTable]`
for Second Table: `table[class=cricket-performanceTable noBorderTop]`

How Can I Parse the Third Table?

Comment: What about print $name[161]?

Comment: @sємsєм he would have to change the 2 element to table without the class definition on his find as from what he said each odd table will hold a different class name.

Comment: Why not use DOMDocument & DOMXPath? `//table[3]//td[1]` and you're done, and a helluvalot faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$src = '<div class="cricket-accorContent">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="cricket-performanceTable"><tr><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr></table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="cricket-performanceTable noBorderTop"><tr><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr></table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="cricket-performanceTable"><tr><td>31</td><td>32</td></tr></table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="cricket-performanceTable noBorderTop"><tr><td>41</td><td>42</td></tr></table>
</div>
';

$html = str_get_html($src);

$thirdTable = $html->find('div[class=cricket-accorContent] table', 2);
$firstTD = $thirdTable->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
$secondTD = $thirdTable->find('td', 1)->plaintext;

echo '-' . $firstTD . '-';
echo '-' . $secondTD . '-';
```

Outputs:

-31--32-